# Receiving TypeError for pd.read_csv -> solved by different name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I just found a really strange behavior of my pyhton program, which just came up a few minutes ago. I was evaluating my program in where I am reading in an .csv file by `price_db = pd.read_csv(f'{filepath}.csv', sep=';')`.
The file which shall be read in is a simple .csv file containing a few lines:

```
time;price;num_of_trades;volume
2020-12-01 13:30:58;0.159;1;940.0
2020-12-01 16:32:58;0.158;2;6000.0
2020-12-01 22:01:43;0.154;3;0.0
```

The filepath is defined in this way:

```
filepath = './database/isin'
```

So again all of a sudden I started to became the following error message:

> Error evaluating: thread_id: pid_15344_id_2298088555280
> frame_id: 2299102155616
> scope: FRAME
> attrs: price_db
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 286, in resolve_compound_variable_fields
> return _typeName, resolver.get_dictionary(VariableWithOffset(var, offset) if offset else var)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_dictionary'

After 30 minutes of google (in where I found nothing helpful), I just renamed `price_db` to `stock_db` and now everything works fine again.

As I am happy for now I would like to understand the reason behind that strange behavior to avoid anything similar in the future. Looking forward to some ideas.

Thank you!

Comment: Please help us help you by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MZ I just edited the question. Hopefully that helps. Thanks!